# IC FLASH replacement?

Tags: integrated-circuit, c, flash

I was working on a schematic design and wanted to modify a part. The part number is W25Q16DWSSIG made by windbound. I'm trying to replace it with an IC flash with a lager storage and faster speed. It has a higher operating voltage. If the pinouts are the same, could it be possible?(the schematics for the ICs can be different)

Comment: higher voltage will be a problem. Unless the I/O operates at the same voltages as the old chip. you'll need a level converter to translate the signal levels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your part is a normal SPI flash. You could look up the pages of Spansion and Micron for a replacement (that's a pretty standard part). You should find dozens (yes, they basically all have the same pinout) in various sizes.

The voltage range should match your SPI interface, otherwise you risk damaging the part or your controller.

Here's an example: 1.8V, 8-pin SOIC package, same pinout: http://www.spansion.com/Support/Datasheets/S25FS-S_00.pdf